# Get messages from BaseMessage

Tags: c#, winforms, sendbird

I have some problems with SendBird.
As the documentation says:

> Load previous messages
>   After creating a query instance from the CreatePreviousMessageListQuery() method and using the Load() method which returns a list of message objects, you can retrieve a set number of previous messages in an open channel. With the returned list, you can display the past messages in your UI once they have loaded

With the following code:

```
mPrevMessageListQuery.Load(30, true, (List<BaseMessage> messages, SendBirdException e) => {
    if (e != null) {
        // Error.
        return;
    }
});
```

But, I cannot get the message from BaseMessage. I need to have UserMessage. How do I do that?

Comment: @zied ben othman: were you able to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

```
    (UsrMSG((UserMessage)baseMessage));

    string UsrMSG(UserMessage message)
    {
        return message.Sender.Nickname + " ha detto: " + message.Message + "\n";
    }
```

IT WAS SO SIMPLE